# Fixing a while loop

Tags: python-2.7

How do I fix the while loop in this code to work only if `age` is 18 and print an error message if it is less than that, and make the program continue even after the wrong zip code?

Here is my code:

```
print "VOTER ELIGIBILITY AND POLLING STATION PROGRAM"
print
print
age= int(raw_input("Enter your age (Type ' 0 ' to exit program) :"))
while age != 18:
    print "ineligible"
    age= int(raw_input("Enter your age (Type ' 0 ' to exit program) :"))
    if age != 0:
        zipcode= int(raw_input("Enter your residence's zip code:"))

        if zipcode == 93305:
            print "Your polling station is 123 Panorama Drive."
        elif zipcode == 93306:
            print "Your polling station is 6143 Fairfax Drive."
        elif zipcode ==93307:
            print "Your polling station is 21121 B Street."
        elif zipcode ==93308:
            print "Your polling station is 863 Desmond Ct."
        elif zipcode == 93309:
            print "Your polling station is 7332 Del Canto Ct."
        else:
            print "Error-unknown zip code"

raw_input("\nRun complete.Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
age = get_age();

while ( age != 0 ) {
    if ( age >= 18 ) ...
    else ...

    age = get_age();
}

exit
```

Comment: http://www2.bakersfieldcollege.edu/cs/pwhitney/privdocs/coms_b10/COMS%20B10%20Assignment%2003%20(polling%20station%20loop).pdf heres the assignment if you wanna see the sample run

Comment: i ran it but even if I typed ages under 18 it would still execute the zipcode block.

Comment: Now you likely have a problem with indentation.  Try retyping the relevant portions into a separate file.  I copied it into a text editor (with the modifications in my answer), made the indentation uniform, and it ran fine.

Comment: heres a link http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a599/IloveJdmsucias/ScreenShot2013-02-09at91942PM_zps45052d84.png to the code

Comment: That's exactly what mine looks like and it works for me. Maybe your indentation is off.  http://pastebin.com/M9d90D1U

Comment: yeah it was indented correctly fixed it; I'm sorry for taking your time and I appreciate your help :)

Comment: No need to apologize. StackOverflow is for help with programming problems, and people are generally happy to help. In the case of homework, less so, but if you've made a genuine good-faith effort to solve a problem and you provide your source code (as you did) you can usually find people who won't have a problem helping. Good luck learning to program and welcome to SO.

Comment: p.s. - Your homework assignment isn't complete. You need to invest some additional effort in output/spacing.  Read the assignment again.